# Cascading of structural Model in verilog using generate and For Loop

Tags: verilog

I am stuck in a very difficult problem. I am new to Verilog. I am not able to cascade a circuit multiple times using a for loop and generate a statement.
I am trying to generate a circuit as shown below:

[image]

The code I have written to implement is as follows:

```
module rightShift(
input [3 : 0] right_data_input,
output [3 : 0] right_data_output
);

assign right_data_output = right_data_input >> 1;
endmodule
module adder(
input [7 : 0] adder_in1,
input [7 : 0] adder_in2,
output [7 : 0] adder_out
);

assign adder_out = adder_in1 + adder_in2;
endmodule
module Mult_1(
input [3 : 0] input1,
input [7 : 0] input2,
output wire [3 : 0] output1,
output wire [7 : 0] output2
);

rightShift rs_obj(.right_data_input(input1), .right_data_output(output1));
adder add_obj(.adder_in1(output1), .adder_in2(input2), .adder_out(output2));
endmodule

module multiply(
input wire [3 : 0] in_a,
output wire [7 : 0] OUT
);

genvar i;

wire [3 : 0] x1 = 8'b0;

GENERATE

    FOR(i = 0;
        i < 4;
        i = i + 1)
    BEGIN
        Mult_1 mult_obj1(
        .input1(in_a), // Need Help IN the FOR LOOP
        .input2(x1),
        .output2(OUT)
        );

    END

    endgenerate

    endmodule
```

It would be very kind if I can be helped in correcting the For loop to execute the attached circuit.

Comment: try to give names to all connections between module in your pictures. Express them as arrays, indexed by 'i'.  All of them, except the first one will fit in the loop. So, use the first one separately from the rest.

Comment: Hi @Serge. I have modified the figure. Please review it. I really donot understand how the output of one structure goes as input to another structure component with for Loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok with a generate loop it could look like the following with fake modules.
Supposedly you have to instantiate a module with a single input and output which you want to cascade.

```
module buffer(input [3:0] in, output [3:0] out);
```

Your top-level module has similar inputs and outputs. In order to connect several instances of modules you need to declare connection wires. I suggest that for this scheme you create an array of them.

```
module top(input [3:0] in, output [3:0] out);

wire [3:0] connector [5]; // an array of 5 elements.
```

now the first module is instantiated with 'in' as its input. My solution is the following here:

```
assign connector[0] = in; 

genvar i;
for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++) begin: cascade
   buffer buf(.in(connector[i-1]), .out(connector[i]));
end
```

With the above scheme you instantiated 4 buffers. It is equivalent to the following.

```
   buffer buf(.in(connector[0]), .out(connector[1])); // [0] is the same as 'in'
   buffer buf(.in(connector[1]), .out(connector[2]));
   buffer buf(.in(connector[2]), .out(connector[3]));
   buffer buf(.in(connector[3]), .out(connector[4])); // i need connector[5] for this. [4] will go to out
```

and finally, you need to assign you output of the top module:

```
assign out = connector[4];

endmodule: top
```

This is one of the possible scenarios. You can come up with a different one and adapt it to your model needs.

Comment: Hi @Serge. What is the cascade in your code? Vivado start generating something separate. It does not cascade the buffer module. Something is slightly missing.

Comment: What is *cascading* in your own opinion? what is exactly wrong with vivado results?

Comment: Your code works great after putting everything in the same file. Thank you @Serge